# Function in a constructor invokes itself somehow

Tags: javascript, class, oop, object

This code throw an error - "cannot read property 'x' of undefined".
I wanted to assign this function and call it later with an argument (function "crash" answer the question about the collision with other object).

```
function Obj(x, y, height, width, type) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;

            if(type == "obstacle") {
                this.speedX = levelManager.level;
            }

            var self = this;
            this.isNotUsed = function() {
                return self.x < 0;
            };

            this.drawSelf = function(img) {
                ctx.drawImage(img, self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height);
            };
            if(type == "hero"){
                this.crash = function(otherObj) {
                    var myLeft = this.x;
                    var myRight = this.x + this.width;
                    var myBottom = this.y + this.height;
                    var otherLeft = (otherObj.x) || 0;  //error occurs here
                    var otherRight = (otherObj.x + otherObj.width) || 0;
                    var otherTop = otherObj.y || 0;
                    var collision = true;

                    if((myBottom < otherTop) ||
                        (myRight < otherLeft) ||
                        (myLeft > otherRight)) {collision = false;}

                    return collision;
                };
            }
        }
var hero = new Obj(0, 0, 40, 40, "hero");
```

Comment: How do you call `crash()` function?

Comment: Do you mean that the `crash` function is invoking itself?

Comment: @gurvinder372 That's what I don't understand either...

Comment: You didn't define `otherObj`

Comment: @daniel432 Do you have any other code running somewhere?

Comment: And here is a problem - I don't call crash function. Function is called after "var hero = new obj[...]" I suppose.

Comment: @daniel432 no way, the code you posted works (see the snippet in my answer). You have some other code somewhere else, please post full example.

Comment: @dayuloli I know that I don't define otherObj - I want to call function "crash" later with an argument. I think that function can't be called during a creation of an object and function is only assigned to constructor.

Comment: @rpadovani You are right that I have other code but this is pretty long and  I wanted to call that function later with an argument. Do you know how to assign function to a class without calling it during a creation of object?

Comment: @daniel432 you're looking to wrong place. The function is not called during the creation of the object: `crash()` is assigned well and it is not called. You're calling it somewhere else.

Comment: @rpadovani Thank You, I know what to do now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code works well (see snippet). The only error you can have if you call `hero.crash()` without any argument. To avoid this, you can change the crash() function adding as first line of the function `otherObject = otherObject || {};`. Or better, as suggested in comments, just return if otherObject is undefined:

```
if (!otherObject) return false;
```

or if it is not an object

```
if (typeof otherObject !== 'object') return false;
```

```js
function Obj(x, y, height, width, type) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;

            if(type == "obstacle") {
                this.speedX = levelManager.level;
            }

            var self = this;
            this.isNotUsed = function() {
                return self.x < 0;
            };

            this.drawSelf = function(img) {
                ctx.drawImage(img, self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height);
            };
            if(type == "hero"){
                this.crash = function(otherObj) {
                    var myLeft = this.x;
                    var myRight = this.x + this.width;
                    var myBottom = this.y + this.height;
                    var otherLeft = (otherObj.x) || 0;  //error occurs here
                    var otherRight = (otherObj.x + otherObj.width) || 0;
                    var otherTop = otherObj.y || 0;
                    var collision = true;

                    if((myBottom < otherTop) ||
                        (myRight < otherLeft) ||
                        (myLeft > otherRight)) {collision = false;}

                    return collision;
                };
            }
        }


var hero = new Obj(0, 0, 40, 40, "hero");
console.log('THIS IS PRINTED')
console.log(hero.crash('{}'));
console.log('BUT FROM HERE NO MORE');
console.log(hero.crash());
```

Comment: It makes no sense to initialise `otherObj` as an empty object. You should just `return false` if there is no argument if you want to support that case

Comment: @Bergi right, updated answer, thanks. I wrote `return -1` cause `return false` is a valid return value.

Comment: I'd guess OP *wants* a valid return value if the intention is really to support calls to the method without arguments. If not, you should just throw. Returning `-1` from a function that otherwise returns a boolean sounds like a bad idea.